# C#/linq: order list of strings by its title ("Article 3", "Article 15")

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of Item objects (C#):

> List itemList.

the Item object has a property Title, with values varying between ("Article 3:", "Article 14:", "Article 233: dfsdf", etc).

when I sort in the regular LINQ way, like this:

```
itemList.OrderBy(p => p.Title).ToList();
```

Article 14 is sorted before Article 3, because it starts with 1. How do I sort this collection in the right way?

Comment: Refactor your class and add a `ArticleNumber int` property, then sort by that. Don't store multiple  informations in a single string property.

Comment: Do all the titles have the same format : "Article <number>:<optional string>"?

Comment: @TimSchmelter agreed, this seems like the cleanest solution, will give that a try. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can define a property with a getter only on the Object, that will load from the Title just the numbers (maybe by splitting the title by " ", or by replacing the Article text, then trimming the result ), and use the new property in the OrderBy.